# C50Rules - how is confidence calculated? (example needed)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

In a `C5.0` ruleset model, how is the confidence associated with a prediction calculated? I know the help file says

> ...the predicted confidence value is the confidence value from the most specific, active rule.

perhaps with normalization as well.

But what is the definition of most specific? The number of cases it applies to? The number of conditions?

A step-by-step walkthrough of the following will be helpful.

```
> library(C50)
> data(churn)
> treeModel <- C5.0(x = churnTrain[, c(3:4,7,10,16)], y = churnTrain$churn,rules=T)
```

Rules:

```
Read 3333 cases (6 attributes) from undefined.data

Rules:

Rule 1: (57, lift 6.8)
    international_plan = yes
    total_intl_minutes > 13.1
    ->  class yes  [0.983]

Rule 2: (20, lift 6.6)
    total_day_minutes > 315.6
    ->  class yes  [0.955]

Rule 3: (52/12, lift 5.2)
    international_plan = no
    total_day_minutes > 223.2
    total_eve_minutes > 267
    ->  class yes  [0.759]

Rule 4: (168/51, lift 4.8)
    total_day_minutes > 264.4
    total_eve_minutes > 167.3
    ->  class yes  [0.694]

Rule 5: (152/58, lift 4.3)
    total_day_minutes > 223.2
    total_eve_minutes > 241
    ->  class yes  [0.617]

Rule 6: (2412/164, lift 1.1)
    international_plan = no
    total_day_minutes <= 223.2
    ->  class no  [0.932]

Rule 7: (2211/160, lift 1.1)
    international_plan = no
    total_day_minutes <= 264.4
    total_eve_minutes <= 241
    ->  class no  [0.927]

Rule 8: (854/84, lift 1.1)
    total_day_minutes <= 315.6
    total_eve_minutes <= 167.3
    ->  class no  [0.901]

Rule 9: (2690/268, lift 1.1)
    total_day_minutes <= 264.4
    total_intl_minutes <= 13.1
    ->  class no  [0.900]

Default class: no
```

The cases:

```
> churnTest[1:2,  c(3:4,7,10,16)]
      area_code international_plan total_day_minutes total_eve_minutes total_intl_minutes
1 area_code_510                 no              70.9             211.9               10.6
2 area_code_510                 no             223.6             244.8                9.5
```

The Prediction:

```
> predict(treeModel, churnTest[1:2,  c(3:4,7,10,16)],type="prob")
        yes        no
1 0.0000000 1.0000000
2 0.2552751 0.7447249
```

How are the predicted probabilities of the two cases calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial answer on [Max Kuhn's blog](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2015/9/8/c50-predicted-probability-shrinkage):

In short, the probability from the `predict` function is a weighted average between the prob shown in the model object and the prior.

I could not exactly reproduce the numbers returned by `predict`, but at least now I know why they are different to that given by the model object.